# Get a single value from user database django

Tags: python, django

im new on django, and i want to get a single value from a queryset, te query would be something like this:

```
select last_task from User where user_id=1
```

I tried with values() and only() but it doesnt work.

```
worker = request.user
Worker.objects.filter(user=worker.id).values("last_board")
```

values() return me a dictionary and i cant extract the single value from it to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for values_list, in particular with flat=True. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

```py
worker = request.user
Worker.objects.filter(user=worker.id).values_list("last_board", flat=True)
```

This will return a flat list of "last_board" values. If there is only one value, then it will return the single value. If there are multiple, it will return a list of values (no dict or unnecessary tuple).

Comment: I think it will always be a list, even with one value

Comment: No, it won't. If there is only 1 value, it will return scalar.

Comment: If you call values_list() without flat=True, then yes, it will return a tuple.

Comment: I am positive that you are wrong, there is no documentation on it and I have never encountered such behavior. Please double check. (Furthermore, it would be really awful API)

Comment: Well, you've used "first". It will always return a scalar or a single instance, no need to type check. The original query didn't have it and the point (as I read it from your answer) was that the values_list's behavior is different depending on the amount of objects in the database, and you will need to type check its return value since you don't know in advance whether it will be a list or a scalar. Anyway, it's getting to long, we may have misundertood each other. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233398/discussion-between-trent-and-alexandr-tatarinov).

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov is right - when using first() there are no type issues. I've removed that comment. I confused myself by mixing flat=True and flat=False in my local testing when making this answer.

Comment: I think you can also use 'get' instead of 'filter'.

Comment: @hs2 - you can use get, just need to make sure you catch DoesNotExist exception around it, filter and first() are a little more forgiving in that regard. Really it's just preference.

Comment: @Trent you are right. I just suggested it because Nuevakenia seems to want to get a single value. I also agree and recommend use 'filter' with 'first'.